# Generate WCF Services and Interfaces from WSDL

Tags: wcf

Could anyone please tell  me whether it's possible to reverse engineer (generate interfaces and services) from WSDL.

The reason being, we would like to generate exactly same industry stanadard WSDL.

Any tool to achieve above will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to be able to take a WSDL and run it through some tool to generate a complete service (including the interfaces and the **implementation** of those interfaces), I don't think there is one.

If you want to generate a proxy to use with a service from its WSDL, you can use the SVCUTIL.EXE tool - [ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool (Svcutil.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx).

Comment: thanks @Tim, yes I'm after some tool to generate a complete service (including the interfaces and the implementation of those interfaces)

Comment: @flybyte - Why? What you seem to want strikes me as at the very least unethical, if not illegal. You want to reverse engineer someone else's code, presumably without their permission (otherwise you wouldn't need to reverse engineer it). WCF services are not that hard to create, and by the time you reverse engineered someone else's you could probably have written your own. Just my 2 cents.  If I misunderstood your intent or purpose, I apologize.

Comment: @flybyte - Ok, so I think I see where you're going (the phrase reverse-engineering through me off).  You want to be able to take a WSDL and generate a complete WCF service from that.  I'm not awqare of any tools to do that; your best bet is to probably do as I said above - generate the proxy via SVCUTIL, and then use that to extract out the interfaces and create your own implementation (you can use the BODs from HR-XML's site to guid you on creating your service).  Hopefully this helps you somewhat.  Again, I apologize for any wrong accusations or implications.